# Integrating Java and Access/SharePoint using UCanAccess and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ucanaccess

Is it possible to open an Access 2013 database file stored in MS SharePoint using UCanAccess (JDBC)?

Comment: The UCanAccess JDBC driver uses Jackcess as its record manager, and Jackcess requires that the Access database be accessible as a "regular file" on a filesystem. So, your question hinges on whether an Access database on SharePoint can be presented to a Java application as a regular file (e.g., `S:\path\to\db.accdb` or `\\server\share\path\to\db.accdb`). I honestly don't know if SharePoint can do that. If we're lucky, Albert will see this question and offer some of his expertise.

Comment: sorry, but who is Albert?

Comment: Albert D. Kallal is another regular contributor to Access questions on SO and is quite knowledgeable about Access Web Applications and SharePoint and stuff.

Comment: Ok thank you! I hope that Albert will see this post!